# MongoDb joining 2 collection not works

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collection **user** and **coupon** I need data that matches **user.referral.id** == **coupon.id**

**user collection**

```
user :{
id : 1,
name : "Abcsd",
referral :{
  id: 31,
  referralPercentage : 10
}
}
```

**coupon Collection**

```
coupon :{
 id: 31,
 code :"AXH"
}
```

**Query**

```
db.user.aggregate([{$lookup:{from:"coupon", localField:"referral.id", foreignField:"id", as :"CouponArray"}}])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It worked.

**data**

```
db={
  "user": [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Abcsd",
      referral: {
        id: 31,
        referralPercentage: 10
      }
    }
  ],
  "coupon": [
    {
      id: 31,
      code: "AXH"
    }
  ]
}
```

**aggregate**

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "coupon",
      "localField": "referral.id",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "CouponArray"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fw4vBHF6dQp)